# angularjs datepicker locale

Tags: angularjs, locale

Как в календаре ангуляра, указать с какого файла локали брать перевод? Не смотря на то, какой язык в данный момент выбран на сайте?

Как вообще работают переводы календаря?

Календарь - `uib-datepicker`

[link to datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepickerPopup)

Comment: о каком datepicker идет речь?

Comment: в ангуляре нет своего календаря, кажется

Comment: ui-bootstrap, я так понимаю что переводы он берет со своих файлов локали. я их нашел. но как мне ему указать какой именно файл в данный момент я хочу использовать. не переводить же мне месяца на нужный мне язык. это как то тупо.

Comment: добавь _ссылку_ на этот компонент

Comment: [говорят](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19676300/2881286) надо просто скрипт с нужной локалью подключить на страницу

Comment: они то подключены. 3 скрипты с 3мя языками. исходя из выбраного языка на странице, дейтпикер переводит как нужно, но в определенный момент, мне необходимо что бы меся был на том языке который нужно мне а не тот что выбрал пользователь на странице. то есть. вопрос в том. как дейтпикеру указывать на каком языке должны быть месяца.

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ возможно вот этот дейтпикер. сложно сказать так как он уже используется до меня.

Comment: сейчас пытаюсь найти, мозможно ли как то не в контроллере а в опшинс дейтпикера указать какой язык испольовать

Comment: а что конкретно ты хочешь перевести?

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать проще - можно добавить локаль по другому, например на [этом сайте](https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime) показывают как сделать такую вещь:

```
var date = new Date(2014, 11, 31, 12, 30, 0);

var options = {
  era: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
  weekday: 'long',
  timezone: 'UTC',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
  second: 'numeric'
};

alert( date.toLocaleString("ru", options) ); // среда, 31 декабря 2014 г. н.э. 12:30:00
alert( date.toLocaleString("en-US", options) ); // Wednesday, December 31, 2014 Anno Domini 12:30:00 PM
```

То есть можно в скрипте дейтпикера написать так:

```
var your_language = 'en-US';
$scope.today = function() {
    $scope.dt = new Date().toLocaleString(your_language, options);
};
```

К сожалению, это всё опционально только для русского, английского и китайского языка.

Comment: о каком _скрипте дейтпикера_ идет речь? имеется ввиду правка исходников bootstrap?

Comment: @Grundy, да, речь идёт о правке исходников, которые указал автор в своем вопросе